# (Java) Erro ao gravar várias linhas em um arquivo TXT

Tags: java

Estou tentando gravar criar um arquivo de log `.txt`.
Consigo validar se o arquivo existe utilizando `If`, porém não consigo gravar fora do `if` onde foi criado o arquivo. Sou iniciante e acredito que o erro está mais na lógica do que o código em si. Como a finalidade é criar um arquivo de log não pode perder as informações já gravadas, deve sempre adicionar novas informações no arquivo.

```
 String path = "C:\\Users\\Ronison Matos\\Documents\\log.txt";
    File file = new File(path);
long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if(file.exists()){


    }else{

           FileWriter(file));
           System.out.println("Criei novo arquivo em branco para você!");
           FileWriter arq = new FileWriter(file);
    }


    PrintWriter gravarArq = new PrintWriter(arq); // Aqui já dá o erro de acessar no "path"
    gravarArq.write("Caminho da gravação: " + path);
    writer.newLine();
    writer.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solução para seu problema é simplificar o teste para existência do arquivo, pois existindo ou não o arquivo você vai usar o [`FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) e retire a declaração `FileWriter arq = new FileWriter(file);` de dentro do `if`.

Crie um novo arquivo com a função [`java.io.File.createNewFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile--) que atomicamente cria um novo arquivo vazio se e somente se um arquivo com este nome ainda não existir.

**Solução:**

```
    String path = "C:\\Users\\Ronison Matos\\Documents\\log.txt";
    File file = new File(path);
    long begin = System.currentTimeMillis(); //?????

     // Verifica se o arquivo não existe
     if(!file.exists()){

       // Como o arquivo não existe cria um novo arquivo
       file.createNewFile();

       System.out.println("Criei novo arquivo em branco para você!");
    }

    // Declara arq fora do escopo do if
    FileWriter arq = new FileWriter(file);

    PrintWriter gravarArq = new PrintWriter(arq); 
    gravarArq.write("Caminho da gravação: " + path);
    writer.newLine();
    writer.close();
```

Comment: Deu certo Augusto pela ajuda e explicação! Muito obrigado!